# how can I use UIImageView on full screen in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am developing a software and in it I am making a new file, which is subclass of UIViewController, when I do use UIImageView, then there is little border remaining in it, what should I do so that my image should cover all area around it,

my coding of UIImageView in ViewDidLoad is

```
UIImageView* view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"frontnew.png"]];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415);
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

now what should I do ????
If I increase height and width then it will increase from two sides, not all ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should  set imageview property as scalltoFit
 May be it can help you

Comment: first of all you should set the frame of the imageview  with the size of the i-phone screen cgrectmake(0,0,320,480) and  also you try this [view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];